# How can I make it work stably and insert as chrome extension?

Tags: javascript

This code performs saving and sorting innerHTMLtext of body by count of times you pressed combination of keys. It works, but at some point of time script stops working at all and it need to be changed or file that contain it has to be renamed to continue working. Besides I tryed add it as Chrome extension and in debug mode I see that script connected (it output conlose.log after DOMContentLoaded event handler), but it skips some blocks of code and after every fix different one. You can see this phenomenon in both "local server" and "browser extension" program modes. I tried somehow work out this problem, looked through a lot of forums and solutions and still don`t have a solution. So it's sad that I can`t end up my first mini project on native js(. Sincerely wish for your guidence.

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let inputEl = document.body;
  inputEl.addEventListener("keydown", copy_paste);
});

console.log('It connected');

let storage = {};

function copy_paste(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == "q") {
    let inputValue = window.getSelection();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(inputValue).then(
      navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
        if (!storage.hasOwnProperty(text)) storage[text] = 1;
        else storage[text] += 1;
        mySort(storage);
      })
    );
  }
}

function show(arrStorage) {
  let parent = document.getElementById("insert");
  parent.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arrStorage.length; i++) {
    let para = document.createElement("h4");
    para.innerText = arrStorage[i][0] + " : " + arrStorage[i][1];
    parent.appendChild(para);
  }
}

function mySort(storage) {
  let arrStorage = [];
  for (let key in storage) {
    arrStorage.push([key, storage[key]]);
  }
  arrStorage.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });
  show(arrStorage);
}
```

Comment: This code works in my local server. Please provide how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hashed tomato
1) It works for sime time and at some point stops it`s performance
2) My goal is to upload it as chrome extension (there is html and manifest files in the project folder), I`ve already uploaded folder in devoper mode as own extension but I see only html page and script refuses to work at all

Comment: This code works in my chrome extension also.  Please provide manifest file and html file.

Comment: @hashed tomato this is project repository on my github https://github.com/mykmar556/words_tier_list.git

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.clipboard.readText()` requires `clipboard-read` permission of Permission API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

The default value of `clipboard-read` is `"prompt"` (in my case) that means calling `.readText()` cause popup message to request permission of clipboard reading.

When your `popup.html` is opened in active tab (by defining `popup.html` as options page in `manifest.json`, for example), the popup message appears at keydown of cntl-q.
After clicking OK in the popup, the permission information is stored in Chrome.
You can see it in:
[chrome://settings/content](http://chrome://settings/content)  or
[chrome://settings/content/all](http://chrome://settings/content/all).

Unfortunately, when `popup.html` is opened as popup of browser action, the permission popup seems to be blocked, and your extension seems to stop.
I dont know why, but gess it is by security reason.

I think there is no way to permit `clipboard-read` in program without user interevension.

Comment: I tried turning on global chrome permissions such as clipboard or popup messages and even both simultaneously but still no any activity or traces of life(